# Restler won't call any API methods

Tags: php, restler

Restler is refusing to instantiate any of my API classes.  It's just always saying it fails on Route, but doesn't bother to provide any other useful information.  I installed Restler via composer via `"restler/framework" : "3.0.0-RC6"` and then created an index.php that looks like this:

```php
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Explorer');
$r->addAPIClass('Play');

$r->handle();
```

In the exact same directory as the index.php I've created a file called Play.php that looks like so:

```php
<?php

public class Play
{
    public function __construct() {
        error_log("I called the constructor!\n", 3, '/tmp/scott');
    }

    public function index() {
        error_log("I called the index\n", 3, '/tmp/scott');
    }
```

When I call `http://.../api/play` I never see the /tmp/scott file created, and I just get the generic failure response from Restler:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found"
    },
    "debug": {
        "source": "Routes.php:438 at route stage",
        "stages": {
            "success": [
                "get"
            ],
            "failure": [
                "route",
                "negotiate",
                "message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like some how class `Play` is not autoloaded. Try var_dump(class_exists('Play')); in your index.php to confirm

Comment: And how do I see that output?

Comment: OK, I used error_log to check the value and it definitely says it does not exist.

Comment: If I explicitly add a require of Play.php to index.php it works.  Not sure if that helps you figure out anything though.

Comment: You have to edit your composer.json to add the folders it has to look for source files. Read about it in https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading You may read the cheat-sheet at http://composer.json.jolicode.com/ and roll over the autload section in composer.json

Answer (score 1):

As Luracast noted in the comments, I had to edit the composer.json to add this stanza:

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "api"
    }
}
```

and then run `composer dump-autoload`